# Can you buy a helipad or hangar in GTA V Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I haven't seen any in the property list. Is it possible they're unlocked at a higher level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Rockstar Social Club website](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/) has added a handy online guide.  It has an entry for the website where you can purchase aircraft from with the following text:

> - Vehicles bought from Elitas Travel can be delivered on request by calling Pegasus – the contact will appear on your phone when you purchase your first vehicle requiring their services.
> - Vehicles delivered by Pegasus will be blipped on the Map, you can then use Quick GPS to navigate directly to your awaiting vehicle – look for ‘Pegasus Vehicle’ in the Quick GPS list.

The description for the website that sells boats is exactly the same.

This leads me to believe that you call it in, and the plane will be delivered to the closest airfield.  Kind of like how the blimp works in Story Mode.

Comment: If anybody that's bought a plane could confirm this, and maybe elaborate on where the plane/helicopter would be dropped off, that'd be cool

Comment: I can confirm this from what another player who had bought one was chatting about in my session yesterday.  He also complained about having to drive across the map to get to it.  So it sounds like it goes to the closest airfield/helipad/marina.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no. Throughout online the only property I see that's buyable are apartments and garages. I'm not completely sure though, since I'm a low level and haven't done to much. This is just the answer from a rookie.

Answer (score 0):

not right now rockstar have said that for the first few weeks there will be limited property availability but in the future there will be ever expanding oppertunities

Comment: Do you have a link to a source to support this?